# How to use wit.ai to return one single result (python)

Tags: python, wit.ai

I have been recently fooling around with wit.ai in python. I have been able to make .interactive() work when communicating with the bot, but I really want .message() to work, since I want to send one message at a time. I saw online that you can do it like this:

```
client = Wit(access_token=token, actions=actions)
resp = client.message('hello')
print(resp)
```

However, the response is not what I want and is actually just the message being sent to the server. Like this:

```
{'msg_id': '516ffc83-f008-446a-979a-2da2207164a1', '_text': 'hello', 'entities': {'intent': [{'confidence': 0.9646306495169545, 'value': 'greeting'}]}}
```

I would like to fetch the callback from the message and print it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation and my personal experience, that response is not the message being sent to the server. It is indeed the response to your query from the server.

Check - https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160330#get-intent-via-text-link

The "intent" map in the "entities" object holds the measure of confidence (i.e 96.4%) with which it predicts the query "hello" to be a "greeting". Now, if you want to parse this JSON response, you can do this -

```
callback = resp['_text']['entities']['intent']['value']
print(callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, so I assume there is no actual way to just get the response that the bot would say and just that response? I would still like it to act like .interactive(), just one message instead of continuing. Thanks

Comment: If you want "message" to behave like "interactive", the method I suggested seems to be the only way. Alternatively, you can capture the response of interactive and go with that. Is there a reason you prefer the former to the latter?

Comment: Well at the moment, I am using google's text to speech. I basically use it to capture input from the user then send and continue. I have been looking at converse which seems to almost be doing the job! Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure :) Don't forget to Upvote and mark the answer if you  found it helpful!